# C# WP8 file disappearing

Tags: c#, file, file-io, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am saving a creating a file in a folder and writing some data to it like this:

```
        if (!Directory.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\BinarySettings"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\BinarySettings");

        string settingFilePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\BinarySettings\\" + setting_Name + ".bindat";
        FileStream binaryFileStream = new FileStream(settingFilePath, FileMode.Create);//If the setting already exists overwrite it otherwise create it
        BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(binaryFileStream);

        binaryWriter.Write(setting_Bytes);
        binaryWriter.Flush();

        //Dispose of the streams after we have finished using them
        binaryWriter.Dispose();
        binaryFileStream.Dispose();

        Debug.WriteLine(File.Exists(settingFilePath));
```

This seems to work fine because using File.Exists on the file after this from anywhere in the application returns true.

The strange thing is that when my application starts again and I want to load the data from the file then it has suddenly disappeared. Trying File.Exists on the file suddenly returns false.

Has this ever happened to any of you and what could cause such bizarre behavior?

Comment: How are you restarting your app? Are you re-deploying from Visual Studio or re-launching from Visual Studio?

Comment: I am not sure, does it make a difference?

Comment: Yes, if you do a rebuild then run then its a clean install and all files are deleted. Try launch/quit/re-launch from within device/emulator. Your files should still be there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it tomorrow when I get back to my pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I was actually reinstalling the application instead of relaunching it. To relaunch it you have to do so from the Windows Phone and not Viusal Studion.